# Array of images P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I create in the preload function an array of images that I want to use later. However, when I want to use the image properties height and width the type is undefined. There is any way to cast or something in javascript?

I tried to create a new image but i miss the image properties, example:

```
    var images = new Array();
function preload() {    
images.push(loadImage("image0.jpg"));

var img=loadImage("image1.jpg");
var aspect = img.height / img.width; // Here I successfully get the image properties
images.push(img);
}

function setup() {
createCanvas(1000, 600);
var imgNum = parseInt(random(0, images.length - 1), 10);
var img1 =images[parseInt(imgNum, 10)];
var aspect = img1.height / img1.width; // Here img1 has undefined type so the value img1.height is undefined too.

            console.log("value: "+aspect);
    image(images[imgNum], 0, 0);
    console.log(img1);
}
```

so the img1.height value is undefined. I guess the interpreter lost the type so there is a way to recover the type and the information? something like the cast in java or c++?

However,  If dont change ask for the properties of the image I'm able to print the image but each image has its own value and I cant resize them.

```
function setup() {
 createCanvas(1000, 600);
 var img1 =images[parseInt(imgNum, 10)];
 image(img1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Most likely, either the `loadImage()` method or the image `src` itself is wrong. That would mean you are creating new Image() objects, but they only have the default value since nothing is loaded into them.

Comment: no the image is the, I can show it in the canvas, what is lost is its properties "img1.height / img1.width" but I can visualize the image, the problem is that I can get the ratio son the images are in different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to narrow the problem down. What happens when you do this?

```
function preload() {
   var img = loadImage("image0.jpg");
   console.log(img.height);
}
```

If this is undefined, then you know something is wrong with that image location. Check the location and spelling. Check out the network tab of your developer tools in your web browser to make sure the file is loading.

What happens when you just run this?

```
var x = parseInt(random(100, width), 10);
console.log(x);
```

What is the value of `x`? Is it what you expect?

Similarly, what value does this evaluate to?

```
parseInt(imgNum, 10)
```

If that makes sense, then move on to this line:

```
var img1 =new p5.Image(images[parseInt(imgNum, 10)]);
```

Why are you doing this? The `images` array should already contain instances of `p5.Image`. This line doesn't really make any sense. You should be able to do something more like this:

```
var img1 = images[2];
```

Note that I've hardcoded the index. Start with that just for testing purposes.

Note that these questions are more for you to ask yourself. This is the process of debugging a problem, and it's what you should do when you have problems like this. Try to isolate the problem by figuring out which parts of the code are working. Then hard-code those parts to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which will help you ask a more specific question. Good luck.

Comment: I also tried the the harcoded as I explain in my question, but it is still undefined. I know that the problem uis this like "var img1 =new p5.Image(images[parseInt(imgNum, 10)]);" because it lost its type, so I can get the properties. But maybe I was doing something wrong I also tried with "images= []" instead of array.

Comment: @aburbanol Like I said, that line doesn't make a ton of sense. The array already holds `p5.Image` instances. You shouldn't ever have to manually create a new instance. Check your network tab to make sure the image file is loading correctly.

Comment: yes I change it for this "var img1 =images[parseInt(imgNum, 10)];" and yes the images are loading, but it dont recognize it as a p5.Image instance. I edit my post with a change taht make it work, but still If I check the type is undefined

Comment: @aburbanol I'm not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't recognize it as a `p5.Image` instance. Can you please edit your post to include one [mcve] that includes all of the code I need to run to see your problem? Please hardcode as much as possible.

Comment: @aburbanol The code you posted doesn't work because `imgNum` is not defined anywhere.